# Simple sum-function in Python with numba doesn't compute

Tags: python, numba

I'm trying to learn Python and Numba and I can't figure out why the following code doesn't compute in IPython/Jupyter:

```
from numba import *

sample_array = np.arange(10000.0)

@jit('float64(float64, float64)')
def sum(x, y):
    return x + y

sum(sample_array, sample_array)
```

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>   ----> 1 sum(sample_array, sample_array)
>
> C:\Users***\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numba\dispatcher.pyc in _explain_matching_error(self, *args, **kws)
>       201         msg = ("No matching definition for argument type(s) %s"
>       202                % ', '.join(map(str, args)))
>   --> 203         raise TypeError(msg)
>       204 
>       205     def **repr**(self):
>
> TypeError: No matching definition for argument type(s) array(float64, 1d, C), array(float64, 1d, C)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are passing in arrays, but your jit signature expects scalar floats. Try the following instead:

```
@jit('float64[:](float64[:], float64[:])')
def sum(x, y):
    return x + y
```

My recommendation is to see if you can get away with not specifying types and just use the bare `@jit` decorator, which will do type inference at runtime and you can more flexibly handle inputs. For example:

```
@jit(nopython=True)
def sum(x, y):
    return x + y

In [13]: sum(1,2)
Out[13]: 3

In [14]: sum(np.arange(5),np.arange(5))
Out[14]: array([0, 2, 4, 6, 8])
```

My experience is that adding the types rarely gives any sort of performance benefit.

Comment: Thank you, Josh! I changed your code a little: `@jit('float64(float64[:], float64[:])')
def sum(x, y):
    return x + y`. I'm wondering, why do you use `@jit(nopython=TRUE)` instead of `@autojit`?

Comment: @JimBoy - `@jit` without specifying the call signature is is the same as `@autojit`. If you look at the current numba docs, `autojit` is deprecated (https://github.com/numba/numba/blob/master/numba/decorators.py). Also, I tend to specify `nopython=True` unless I specifically know that I'm going to be doing requiring 'object mode' (see http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.21.0/glossary.html), as this ensures that I get a compilation error if numba doesn't support compiling everything down to native code. This is usually a warning sign that numba isn't doing what I expect it to be doing

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was because i was passing 2d array (matrix) but it was expecting 1d array (vector)